# Java Jetty configure contextPath issue

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I've just started experimenting with Java and found [this websocket demo tutorial](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/web-socket/web-socket-helloworld.html)

Now I'am running this demo app with `mvn jetty:run` command but then I can't get needed `web-socket-client.html` page in the browser. I don't know how to configure `<contextPath>` for Jetty correctly to serve my app from the project folder.

This is my project structure:

[image]

And this is what I get on my VDS `https://example.com/example` address:

[image]

There is no access to any other file or path while running jetty on my VDS.

How to configure Jetty for serving this demo app correctly on my VDS?

Answer (score 0):

Jetty `9.4.1.v20170120` is getting rather long in the tooth (aka old), consider using something more recent, such as `9.4.12.v20180830`.

The plugin `jetty-maven-plugin` is for working with Web Applications, aka WAR files.

This means ...

- Your project pom should have `<packaging>war</packaging>`
- Your project structure should be for a standard Servlet Web App

  - such as the `src/main/webapp` directory

Comment: Thank you very much for info! I'll try to configure project enviroment properly. It's a pity that there is no notes for this demo project.

Comment: That demo could be an [tag:embedded-jetty] setup instead.  If that's the case, you wouldn't use the `jetty-maven-plugin`, but rather just execute whatever `main()` class the demo comes with.

Comment: I don't know why, but the latest version of Jetty plugin just doesn't serve the webapp. It just builds project and then shutdown